# How to calculate the area of a roll?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider we have a roll of paper with the size of `5 cm` in diameter and `10 cm` in width. If the thickness of the paper sheet is `0.05 cm`, and the rolling has been started from the point zero (the internal reel is 0cm), how can we calculate the length or area of the whole paper sheet?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvQ8.jpg)

Comment: The duplicate question has extensive discussion.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's find the number of wraps: $2.5/0.05=50$. Now, the radius of the first wrap will be 0.05, the second: $0.05\cdot 2$, $k-th$ radius will be $0.05k$. The area of one wrap will be $2 \cdot 0.05 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot 10=k\pi$. So we have area $$A=\sum_{k=1}^{50}k\pi=25\cdot 51 \cdot \pi$$

Comment: both of these answers are approximations to the correct answer, but only approximations - the roll is a spiral and not made of concentric rings. The top profile of the roll is not a circle!

Comment: I agree that the outer layer may not be the complete circle so it is an approximation but all inner layers should be circular, no?